# Can't understand why I am getting tuple error even though I typed everything correctly

Tags: python

### I am trying to get 'Hi' and 'Hello' together using identifiers

INPUT:

```
ankur="Hi"
yash="Hello"
print(ankur, yash)
```

OUTPUT (Error):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-733bc20e4385> in <module>()
      1 ankur="Hi"
      2 yash="Hello"
----> 3 print(ankur, yash)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Look at the rest of your code and try to find where you've assigned something to *print*. It seems that you have overriden (shadowed) the built-in function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a jupyter notebook. In previous or deleted cells you have redefined the print function to be a tuple. try to input only `print` without parenthesis to see what value it has.

To solve the issue, just restart the kernel.

Input

```
type(print)
```

output

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Only restarting the kernel solved my problem, thanks